# How to add "layout" attribute in Strings.xml of Android resource file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

So this is my strings.xml file:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.draw.map"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

 <style name="dialogBottomIncludeStyle" >
            <item name="tools:layout">@layout/include_dialog_bottom</item>
        </style>
```

also tried

```
<style name="dialogBottomIncludeStyle" >
            <item name="layout">@layout/include_dialog_bottom</item>
        </style>
```

An error appears saying says "**error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'tools:layout'.**"

Thanks for your time

**But in my layout file am able to add "layout" attribute**

Comment: Hey, I'm trying the same and couldn't find anything for the same. Did you get any answer for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<resources>
    <string name="styleattributeinresource"> &lt;style name="dialogBottomIncludeStyle" >
        &lt;item name="tools:layout">@layout/include_dialog_bottom&lt;/item>
        &lt;/style></string>

</resources>
```

Comment: this just a string i suppose not a style cmponent hence it doesnt work for the above issue